# Typescript: How can I get return type of function based on argument type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want return type to be based on "config" argument

now return type of exampleFn function is empty {}

```js
interface Interface {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}
const DEFAULT_VALUES = {
    a: (num: number) => 1 + num,
    b: (str: string) => 'a' + str,
}
const exampleFn = <T extends Partial<Interface>>(config: T) => {
    const map = {};

    Object.entries(config).forEach(([key, val]) => {
        map[key] = DEFAULT_VALUES[key];
    });
    
    return map;
};

const example1 = exampleFn({ a: 123 }); // I want example1 return type to be "{a: (num: number) => number}"
const example2 = exampleFn({ b: 'asd' }); // I want example2 return type to be "{b: (str: string) => string}"
const example3 = exampleFn({ a: 123, b: 'asd' }); // I want example3 return type to be "{a: (num: number) => number, b: (str: string)} => string"
```

is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler won't be smart enough to figure this out on its own, but you can certainly describe the type you want and use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) inside the implementation of `exampleFn()` to prevent it from complaining... keeping in mind that such type assertions shift the burden of type safety from the compiler to you.

Here's the type I think you want:

```
{ [K in Extract<keyof T, keyof Interface>]: typeof DEFAULT_VALUES[K] }
```

Basically you are making a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) where the keys are the keys from `T` which are also present in `Interface` (it is possible for `T` to contain more keys because `T extends Partial<Interface>` allows such extension; if you really want to prohibit this you can, but for now I'm going to leave this as you have it), and the values are the corresponding types from the `DEFAULT_VALUES` value.

Here's the implementation:

```
const exampleFn = <T extends Partial<Interface>>(config: T) => {
   const map = {} as any;

   Object.entries(config).forEach(([key, val]) => {
      map[key] = DEFAULT_VALUES[key as keyof Interface];
   });

   return map as { [K in Extract<keyof T, keyof Interface>]: typeof DEFAULT_VALUES[K] };
};
```

You can see that I am asserting that `key` is `keyof Interface` (since `key` is only known to be `string` by the compiler) and that `map` is the desired return type.  Let's see how it works:

```
const example1 = exampleFn({ a: 123 });
console.log(example1.a(123)); // 124
console.log(example1.b); // undefined
// error!  --------> ~
// Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: (num: number) => number; }'
const example2 = exampleFn({ b: 'asd' });
console.log(example2.b("asd")); // aasd
const example3 = exampleFn({ a: 123, b: 'asd' });
console.log(example3.b("asd")); // aasd
console.log(example3.a(123)); // 124
```

Looks good to me.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#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-ot+WtyH8URYlRirp3KbTvqP+6O1DMACJlpVXxG6NHY3APzuY57hAzqmsBJ4LnaTr-OeH7XuSt6et6D7AY6z5vh+X65n+AHukh6aPiBwahk636-nG8ZAA)